# JWplayer streaming from webcam

Tags: javascript, html, red5, wowza

I need some help understanding how to proceed from here.
i am creating a web app that needs:

1. open in one page client camera computer and show the client himself 
   while streaming him to my Red5 server (like Wowza).
2. from the second page i need to embed the video to the users live from his camera.

i want to do the code with JWplayer.

So far i have only the embed video stream code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>JW Player</title>


<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/MyKeyFromJWplayer.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "rtmp://192.168.1.3/OflaDemo",
    image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg", // what is this image for ?
    height: 360,
    width: 640
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do i do the second part with the camera ?

my seconds question is in this path what exactly do i need to put ?
a file name like mp4 or something ? "rtmp://192.168.1.3/OflaDemo"

does the client is getting "recorded" to a file while he is on his webcam ?
Do i need to use in my code the Red5 ports (5080, 1935) ? and if so where ?

Many questions, i know, but i will really need help here, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so all i had to do is:

rtmp://192.168.1.3/live/live=demo

and from the webcam streaming i put to stream to this file